# How can I create a **dynamic** "p:menu" whose "p:menuitem" elements contain both an "ActionListener" and "Action" attribute?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

***QUESTION***:  How can I create a DYNAMIC "p:menu" that is equivalent to the working STATIC "p:menu", below *(whose menuitems are defined with **both** "actionListener" and "action" attributes)*?

```
    (.xhtml)
    -
    -
    -
    <p:menu id="menustatic" >
        <p:menuitem id="menuitemstatic0" value="operationStatic0"  actionListener="#{testController.staticMenuActionListener}" action="#{breadCrumb.navigate('page0')}" />
        <p:menuitem id="menuitemstatic1" value="operationStatic1"  actionListener="#{testController.staticMenuActionListener}" action="#{breadCrumb.navigate('page1')}" />            
    </p:menu>
    -
    -
    -
```

NOTE:  I understand I can use DefaultMenuItem's "setCommand" to add either an "ActionListener" attribute,  ***OR***, an "Action" attribute...
- But, I do not know how I can add *both* attributes like the above static "p:menu" example.

FWIW, this is how I'm currently adding either one or the other attributes...

```
    (.xhtml)
    -
    -
    -
    <p:menu id="menudynamic" model="#{menuController.dynamicMenuModel}"  />  
    -
    -
    -


    (.java)
    -
    -
    -
    dynamicMenuModel = new DynamicMenuModel();
    //dynamicMenuModel.generateUniqueIds();

    DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem();
    item.setId("menuitemdynamic0");
    item.setValue("operationDynamic0");
    item.setCommand("#{testController.dynamicMenuActionListener}");
    //item.setCommand("#{breadCrumb.navigate('page0')}");
    dynamicMenuModel.addElement(item);

    item = new DefaultMenuItem();
    item.setId("menuitemdynamic1");
    item.setValue("operationDynamic1");
    //item.setCommand("#{testController.dynamicMenuActionListener}");
    item.setCommand("#{breadCrumb.navigate('page1')}");
    dynamicMenuModel.addElement(item);
    -
    -
    -
```

The ActionListener methods look like this...

```
public void staticMenuActionListener(ActionEvent e)
{
    LOG.info("___________________staticMenuActionListener(ActionEvent e)___________________entering....(static)....e.getComponent().getClientId()=" + e.getComponent().getClientId());
}

public void dynamicMenuActionListener(ActionEvent e)
{
    MenuActionEvent me = (MenuActionEvent) e;        
    LOG.info("___________________dynamicMenuActionListener(ActionEvent e)___________________entering....(dynamic)....me.getMenuItem().getClientId()=" + me.getMenuItem().getClientId());
}
```

Here are some relevant dependencies I use to build this test...

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0.9</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Compiling with JDK 1.6.x   (weblogic12c)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

For navigation you could use the item.setOutcome or item.setUrl methods.

Regarding actions, if you need to pass parameters in ajax or non-ajax commands, use setParam(key, value) method.